# Giving an attribute a value with two url's

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm currently having fun with Nodejs and I have a little problem.
I have a div element with inline style attribute. Inside it I only have background-image with one url value. Using Nodejs I'm trying to change the value from one url to two.

Here's an example:

From:

```
<div id="bg" style="background-image: url('img/img1.png')"></div>
```

To:

```
<div id="bg" style="background-image: url('img/img2.png'), url('img/img3.png')"></div>
```

Unfortunately whenever I do so, the new file comes out unchanged. Any ideas as to why?

Nodejs code below:

```
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

var dom = new JSDOM(template, {contentType: "text/html", includeNodeLocations: true,})
var backgrounds = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("*[style]");
    
for (var m = backgrounds.length; m--; ) {
  var bg = backgrounds[m];
  var bg_name = bg.style.backgroundImage;
  bg.style.backgroundImage = `url('img/img2.png'), url('img/img3.png')`
}

fs.writeFile('test/check.html',dom.window.document.documentElement.outerHTML ,{overwrite: true,})
```

Edit:
adding quotes to the url's did not fix the problem as well

Comment: updating a style does not set the attribute of the element.

Comment: ^^ so your maybe after -> `bg.setAttribute('style', '......')`...

Comment: There's a quote missing at the end of the second URL

Answer (score -1):

There are missing single quotes.

New code:

```js
for (var m = backgrounds.length; m--; ) {
  var bg = backgrounds[m];
  var bg_name = bg.style.backgroundImage;
  bg.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/img2.png'), url('img/img3.png')"
}
```